Convert checkoutSCM from stashblue jenkins to github jenkins
I am trying to convert / equivalent of checkoutSCM in github.
BitBucket: checkoutSCM repo: test-pattern', gitInstance: 'stashblue', branch: "origin/pull-requests/${PULL_REQUEST_ID}/from", checkoutDir: 'src'

Equivalent in Github :
    checkoutSCM gitInstance: 'ghec', org: 'abc', repo: 'test.pattern' branch: "origin/pull-requests/${PULL_REQUEST_ID}/from", checkoutDir: 'src'

I tried changing this part -  branch: "origin/pull/${PULL_REQUEST_ID}/from" but it did not work and says revision is invalid
What could be equivalent of branch in GitHub ?

What is this checkoutSCM step? It is not a Jenkins step for as far as i know.
